# which quantile select when doing quantile regression

Tags: quantile-regression

I want to know how strongly a variable restricts the maximum values another variable can reach. I asume there will be some degree of error in my estimates of both variables. Also, the availability of data is not uniform all across the sampling space. Given that situation, I would like to know a method for selecting the most apropriate quantile on which perform the regression which will truly inform me how strongly the predictor variable restricts the maximum value of the response variable.

Example data are here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywvkza8guut9ea0/data.csv?dl=0

the script to do the test in r is here:

```
x=read.csv("data.csv")
require(quantreg)
m=rq(response~predictor, tau = .80, data = x)
with(x,plot(response~predictor))
abline(m)
```

in this example, when doing the regression on the 95th quantile, the slope seems too affected by two data points and does not represent the strong restriction exerted by the predictor on the response. Is there any method to objectively select a "best" quantile to test for the strength of such restriction?

Comment: 1) You will necessarily have a biased estimate of the maximum possible value, if there even is a maximum possible value that your conditional distribution can attain (think uniform vs normal). 2) You want your regression to be affected by extreme points. Those extreme points are possible. 3) If you are winding up with a higher maximum possible value than you would like, perhaps that just means that information from the other data is telling you that when x=whatever, a very large value is possible. Another possibility is to introduce some nonlinearity so your regression line can bend.

Comment: Thank you, but would there a method to select the best quantile over which make the regression, or should i look for the highest quantile (eg.100th), in this case?

Comment: The 100th quantile will be a problem. Consider what happens when you have a Gaussian response variable. Even a bounded variable will be problematic.

Comment: I iteratively obtained the AIC of models with progressively higher quantiles, from .05 to .95. I found that for some cases, the lowest AIC is achieved by the model whose slope best applies to the observed contrain. however, in some others (with less observations) the lowest AIC comes when i use the central quantiles (around .5). Any idea of what would that mean? I would expect the central quantiles to generally have lower AIC because the line passes close to more observations, but that is not always the case.